# Extracting vectors from a dataframe using a Boolean matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, boolean

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.692154 | 0.286560 | 0.515904 |
| 1 | 0.798917 | 0.777593 | 0.971300 |

and I have another matrix which is a Boolean matrix that looks something like this:

```py
b_matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0,1,1],
                       [1,1,0],
                       [0,0,1],
                       [0,1,0]]),                                             
                       columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
                       index = ['input1', 'input2', 'input3', 'input4'])
```

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| input1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| input2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| input3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| input4 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

So the idea here is that I will provide some input, this will be checked against `b_matrix` and then I will have returned to me only the corresponding columns of `df`. e.g. if the input is `input1` then the output will be `df[['col2', 'col3']]`:

|  | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.286560 | 0.515904 |
| 1 | 0.777593 | 0.971300 |

I can think of a way to do this with keeping a static list of the column names to check over each time but I was wondering if there was a more direct method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`input`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_user_input.asp) to take user input and [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
In [1076]: inp = input('User input:')
User input:input1

In [1077]: df[b_matrix.columns[b_matrix.loc[inp].eq(1)]]
Out[1077]: 
       col2      col3
0  0.179902  0.832655
1  0.444187  0.487146
2  0.879333  0.756792
3  0.870601  0.661337
4  0.082169  0.008669
5  0.190734  0.975966
6  0.839718  0.290976
7  0.862724  0.426222
8  0.581909  0.333300
9  0.949953  0.539106
```

If you choose `input2`:

```
In [1080]: inp = input('User input:')
User input:input2

In [1081]: df[b_matrix.columns[b_matrix.loc[inp].eq(1)]]
Out[1081]: 
       col1      col2
0  0.072600  0.179902
1  0.126708  0.444187
2  0.646533  0.879333
3  0.673643  0.870601
4  0.313205  0.082169
5  0.951917  0.190734
6  0.076799  0.839718
7  0.294087  0.862724
8  0.240569  0.581909
9  0.851999  0.949953
```